# Redirect to a URL that is also a Rewrite?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect, url-rewrite-module

I have a customer who has a site(awesomeco.com). On the the site they have a product called "good-stuff" the url is awesomeco.com/good-stuff. They want to move that folder and place it at awesomecogoodstuff.com. Unfortunately, due to the .net cms they are using, we are not able to move that folder out into it's own site. I have a rewrite rule that is handling the rewrite and it works perfectly.

Here's the code:

```
<rule name="awesomecogoodstuff.com rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="awesomecogoodstuff.com />
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\.png|\.css|\.jpg|\.svg|\.ico|\.icon|\.woff|\.js|\.ttf" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/good-stuff/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Unfortunately, the customer wants a redirect rule that will take awesomeco.com/good-stuff and send it off to awesomecogoodstuff.com.

I've tried a few things and either they won't work or it gets into a redirect loop and crashes.

Example, this rule would blow up the site:

```
<rule name="redirect to new domain" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="awesomeco.com/good-stuff" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://awesomecogoodstuff.com" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I can achieve this with small "hack". When you rewriting, just add querystring parameter:

```
<rule name="awesomecogoodstuff.com rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="awesomecogoodstuff.com />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\.png|\.css|\.jpg|\.svg|\.ico|\.icon|\.woff|\.js|\.ttf" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/good-stuff/{R:0}?rewrite=true" />
</rule>
```

And then in your redirect rule, just check if this query string is not present:

```
<rule name="redirect to new domain" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^good-stuff" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="redirect=true" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^awesomeco.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://awesomecogoodstuff.com" redirectType="Found" />                    
</rule>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a little crazy solution, but it might work and meet your needs.

You could check the page onload via JavaScript:

```
<script>
if(window.location.href.indexOf("good-stuff") > -1) {
       window.location = 'http://awesomecogoodstuff.com';
    }
</script>
```

It would fix your problem and you wouldn't run into conflicts with rewrite/redirect rules.